# Specify range of Json array from different column

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0, json-path

Mysql 8 makes it possible to extract part of an array saved in a JSON column as shown below:

`` SELECT jcol->>'$[1 to 5]' FROM `db`.`table` ``  which 1 and 5 are boundaries of the desired range of elements in array.

My question is how to specify the range by numbers from different column. Some thing like this:
`` SELECT jcol->>'$[table2.from to table2.to]' FROM `db`.`table` ``

Comment: You must build the JSON path using common string processing. ```SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jcol, CONCAT('$[', table2.from, ' to ', table2.to, ']'))) FROM db.table```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must build the JSON path using common string processing.

```sql
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jcol, CONCAT('$[', table2.from, ' to ', table2.to, ']'))) 
FROM db.table
```

The JSON path is literal and it is not evaluated as an expression, so you must use `CONCAT()` for the path building.

And the expression usage does not allow to use `->>` operator, you must use `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT())` instead.